# Redirect visitors from one page to another

Tags: html, redirect

We changed our website domain name for our knowledge base website. I would like to ensure visitors only hit our new domain and not the old. After researching, it sounds like server-side redirects is the best way, however I only have the ability to adjust the markup, and I cannot simply turn off the old domain. So I thought redirecting might be good.

Old domain is **widgets.freshdesk.com** and new domain is **support.widgets.com**

When someone hits this page:

```
https://widgets.freshdesk.com/folder/1234/test?blah=123&page=2
```

I would like them to be redirected to the same page but at the new domain:

```
https://support.widgets.com/folder/1234/test?blah=123&page=2
```

What would be the best way to implement this, or as close of a solution as I can get, given my limitation that I cannot redirect server side? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Javascript** for redirect:

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 url = url.replace("widgets.freshdesk.com", "support.widgets.com");
 window.location = url;
```

Put This script in head.

Comment: That sounds like it will work, but I only want this code to be executed if the user is actually on https://widgets.freshdesk.com. If they are at for example another instance viewing this same content (maybe an offline copy) that happens to have that phrase in the URL, I don't want that to happen.